# Which multivariate mutual information approach is better?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, information-theory, mutual-information

Mutual information is non-negative and measures the reduction in uncertainty from knowing one random variable based on the value of another variable,

$$I(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y) - H(X,Y)$$

Below are three versions of **multivariate mutual information**.

1. **Mutual information in matrix form**, which has pair-wise $I(X,Y)$'s in the off-diagonals, and individual entropies $H(X)$ in the diagonals
2. **Total correlation**, which is essentially the KL-divergence between an individual probability distribution's entropy versus the joint entropy of the other distributions

$$TC(X_1,\dots,X_m) = \sum_{i} H(X_i) - H(X_1,\dots,X_m)$$

3. Multivariate **higher-degree mutual-information**, which was proven to possibly contain negative mutual-information values for degrees higher than 2.

My main question is, aren't #1 and #2 identical? If not, what is their relationship or condition for equivalence?

Next I was wondering, is #2 just a scalar, or is it supposed to also be tiled in matrix form, each element representing a different variable's $TC$?

Besides this, isn't #3 clearly the weakest approach since a positive definite matrix is more sought after?

Any other alternatives out there besides the ones listed?